# WampServer suddenly so slow, localhost won't load

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I'm not sure if Windows did an update that affected it, but WampServer is suddenly so slow, localhost either crashes after a few minutes, or a page will finally load. It's a WordPress site by the way (not that that should matter). I've changed nothing. In fact, I was away from my computer for a couple days and this is suddenly happening on my return. Did an update or anything happen that could have caused it? Each page will literally hang for 2-3 minutes and finally load or crash. I've looked thru other sites and made sure the host is 127.0.0.1 vs localhost and cgi_module is unchecked (among other things). It worked fine before this.

Comment: UPDATE: I've noticed that the Antimalware Service Executable in windows goes crazy every time I try to load a localhost page. In the task manager, power usage shoots up to Very High the entire time the page is trying to load.

Comment: I got the same issues suddenly. I am not aware that Windows 10 did any updates recently. There are some updates waiting for download and installation. I can see the Antimalware Service Executable is working crazy if I try to load a web page from Apache local server. After having add exclusion, it stops finally and the web page is loaded normally now.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: It was definitely the Antimalware Service Executable. Found this fix:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028485/windows-10-add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security

Now it's running faster than ever. It must have been the windows update.